# C# immutability.. a lie?

Tags: c#, multithreading, immutability

It is one ideal practice in a multithreaded environment to clone objects (eg: a list) to promote immutability. However if we do so it can be a lie to the API users. What I'm saying is that..

Consider the following code:

```
public class Teacher {

    public List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();

    public Student GetStudent(int index) {
        return Students[index].Clone();
    }
}

public class Student {
    public DateTime LastAttended { get; set; }
}
```

and the users of the API could have done so:

```
var teacher = new Teacher();
var student3 = teacher.GetStudent(3);

student3.LastAttended = DateTime.Now;
```

Without proper documentation the user could not have known the student object he is getting is actually a cloned object and in which case all changes made to the object will not reflect the original one.

How can the code above be improved in a way for the user to know intuitively that the GetStudent is meant only for reading and not for modification? Is there any way to force / restrict from modifying the Student object returned from the GetStudent method?

Comment: That's not what immutability means.  And, you're right; that's a bad idea unless well-documented.

Comment: `GetStudent` and `GetStudentClone`... that's self documenting.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `struct`s?

Comment: Who says that it's an ideal practice to clone to provide immutability? If you want immutability, make immutable objects in the first place, or use property setters that prevent certain modifications (but Reflection will still work).

Comment: BTW, if you really expect anyone to call that method you'd better make the list `private`. Otherwise people might just do `Teacher.Students[0]` and the like.

Comment: I take it you're implementing the [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ICloneable.aspx) interface? You should look at the documentation and read up on the difference between deep and shallow copies. It's up to you to decide how the `Clone` method works. Which means that the documentation is up to you, too. If you want to prevent modification, return a `ReadOnlyStudent` or do what others have suggested and make immutable objects to start with.

Answer (score 4):

Your Student object isn't immutable at all. If you want immutability, make an immutable object:

```
public sealed class Student {
    private readonly DateTime _lastAttended;
    public DateTime LastAttended { get { return _lastAttended; } }

    public Student(DateTime lastAttended)
    {    
        _lastAttended = lastAttended;
    }
}
```

If you don't want someone to set the value of a property, then do not expose a setter, only a getter.

This of course requires architecting the application around this. If you actually need to update the LastAttended time, you would do that e.g. through a Repository that updates the Database and returns a new Student object. Also, many ORMs can't automatically handle immutable objects and need some translation code.

Note that your issue is super-common when people cache objects in Memory and then pass them along, e.g. to View Models which manipulate them, unknowingly modifying the master-object in the cache. This is why cloning is often recommended for Caches. Cloning protects you from code making modifications to "your" objects - every time someone asks, they get a new instance of your master object. Cloning does not prevent the caller to mess up his own version.

Note that declaring a Field as readonly doesn't do much if the Type of the Field is a mutable type - I could still do e.g. `Student.Course.Name = "Test";` even if Course were `readonly` - I cannot change the reference in the Student object, but I can access any property setters.

True immutability is a bit of a pain in C# as it's a lot of typing and a lot of factory methods. At some point, it may be okay to just leave a normal mutable Get/Set and trust that callers know what to do as they can only mess up themselves, not you. That said, anything that actually manipulates the data in the database needs proper security/business rule checks.